# generic free function doesn't free generic values in a generic map

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm making a generic map in c (using clion) and in my nodeDestroy function I call a generic freeing function to free the key and data of the node list. 
nodeDestroy:

```
void nodeDestroy(Node node) {
     Node current = node;
     Node next;
     while (current != NULL) {
        next = current->next;
        current->free_key(current->key);
        current->key = NULL;
        current->free_data(current->data);
        current->data = NULL;
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }
    node = NULL;
}
```

this is the node struct:

```
struct node_t{
    MapKeyElement key;
    MapDataElement data;
    Node next;
    copyMapKeyElements copy_key;
    copyMapDataElements copy_data;
    freeMapKeyElements free_key;
    freeMapDataElements free_data;
};
```

I am testing the map with integer pointers (the data and key of each node are int*) and this is the integer freeing function:

```
static void freeInt(MapKeyElement e) {
    free((int*)e);
}
```

free_key and free_data are given to me in nodeCreate and both are set to freeInt. When I check this in valgrind the key and data of each node aren't freed. any idea?

So I noticed the problem occurs only when using another function: mapPut. I'll add implementation of functions required to understand the code and some things I didn't add before.

```
/** Data element data type for map container */
typedef void* MapDataElement;

/** Key element data type for map container */
typedef void* MapKeyElement;

/** Type of function for copying a data element of the map */
typedef MapDataElement(*copyMapDataElements)(MapDataElement);

/** Type of function for copying a key element of the map */
typedef MapKeyElement(*copyMapKeyElements)(MapKeyElement);

/** Type of function for deallocating a data element of the map */
typedef void(*freeMapDataElements)(MapDataElement);

/** Type of function for deallocating a key element of the map */
typedef void(*freeMapKeyElements)(MapKeyElement);

struct Map_t{
Node iterator;
copyMapKeyElements copy_key;
copyMapDataElements copy_data;
freeMapKeyElements free_key;
freeMapDataElements free_data;
compareMapKeyElements compare_keys;
Node head;
};

bool mapContains(Map map, MapKeyElement element){
if (map == NULL || element == NULL){
    return false;
}
mapGetFirst(map);
if (getKey(map->iterator) != NULL && map->compare_keys(getKey(map->iterator)
                                                          , element) == 0){
    return true;
}
while (mapGetNext(map) != NULL){
    if (getKey(map->iterator) != NULL &&
                    map->compare_keys(getKey(map->iterator), element) == 0){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}

MapResult mapPut(Map map, MapKeyElement keyElement, MapDataElement dataElement){
if (map == NULL || keyElement == NULL || dataElement == NULL){
    return MAP_NULL_ARGUMENT;
}
MapDataElement data_copy = map->copy_data(dataElement);
if (data_copy == NULL){
    return MAP_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
}
MapResult result = MAP_SUCCESS;
if (mapContains(map,keyElement) == true){
    mapGetFirst(map);
    while (map->iterator != NULL){
        if (map->compare_keys(keyElement, getKey(map->iterator)) == 0) {
            map->free_data(getData(map->iterator));
            setData(map->iterator, data_copy);
            return setIterator(map, MAP_SUCCESS);
        }
        map->iterator = getNext(map->iterator);
    }
}
mapGetFirst(map);
MapKeyElement key_copy = map->copy_key(keyElement);
if (key_copy == NULL){
    map->free_data(data_copy);
    return setIterator(map, MAP_OUT_OF_MEMORY);
}
if (getKey(map->iterator) == NULL){
    setKey(map->iterator, key_copy);
    setData(map->iterator, data_copy);
    return setIterator(map, MAP_SUCCESS);
}
Node new_node = nodeCreate(map->copy_data, map->copy_key,
                             map->free_data, map->free_key, &result);
if (result == MAP_OUT_OF_MEMORY) {
    map->free_data(data_copy);
    map->free_key(key_copy);
    return setIterator(map, MAP_OUT_OF_MEMORY);
}
setData(new_node, data_copy);
setKey(new_node, key_copy);
if (map->compare_keys(key_copy, getKey(map->iterator)) < 0){
    setNext(new_node,map->iterator);
    map->head = new_node;
    return setIterator(map, MAP_SUCCESS);
}
while(map->iterator != NULL) {
    if (getNext(map->iterator) == NULL){
        setNext(map->iterator, new_node);
        break;
    }
    if (map->compare_keys(key_copy, getKey(getNext(map->iterator))) < 0){
        Node temp_next = getNext(map->iterator);
        setNext(map->iterator, new_node);
        setNext(new_node, temp_next);
        break;
    }
    map->iterator = getNext(map->iterator);
}
return setIterator(map, MAP_SUCCESS);
}

static MapResult setIterator(Map map, MapResult result){
map->iterator = NULL;
return result;
}

MapKeyElement mapGetFirst(Map map){
if (map == NULL){
    return NULL;
}
map->iterator = map->head;
return getKey(map->head);
}
```

Comment: What is `MapKeyElement`? How do you create your nodes and data? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: After reading the documenation for `free()` ( e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free ), why did you decide to cast to int-pointer? `MapKeyElement` is either a pointer (any), then it does not need casting, or it is no pointer, then casting does not help.

Comment: I wrote a simple program based on your code above, and `valgrind` reports, `All heap blocks were free -- no leaks are possible.` As the other commenters point out, you need to show us more of your code.

Comment: I solved the problem. The issue was that when inserting a new key and data to the map I used malloc to create a copy of the given key that needs to be inserted. Then, after that I called a setting function to set the key and data of the new element in the map, but forgot that this function also creates a copy and then sets the given key and data.